# Error installing rpi.gpio on minibian

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am new to raspberry pi and following a series of online tutorials. I installed minibian according to the tutorial. everything was working fine until I had to install rpi.gpio. I am getting the following error upon entering

```
> pip install rpi.gpio

 Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rpi.gpio
```

I tried the other method to download from the link provided in another question on this forum but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried using the same as you mentioned. but still it would give the same error.

Comment: You should comment to the answer. Joan will not see your reply above.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong name.  Try

`pip install RPi.GPIO`